# Angular 2 routing with Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I have been unsuccessful in getting Angular 2 routing to load a sub module using a webpack generated bundle.

There is a single application bundle (bundle.js) being generated starting at main.ts that is loaded via a script tag in my main html file.  The Angular app starts at AppModule who has a 'home' route that tries to load a child module (HomeModule).  When the target of that 'home' route is a component, there is no issue and the component displays correctly.  However I can't figure out how to correctly specify the route target as a module.  Using the route in the code below (in app.routes.ts), I'm getting the following error.

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Below is the relevant code.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');

var webpackConfig = {
    entry: {
        bundle: "./app/main.ts",
        vendor: "./app/vendor.ts",
        polyfills: "./app/polyfills.ts",
        styles: "./css/app.less.css"
    },

    output: {
        publicPath: '/app/dist/bundles/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/bundles'),
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, './app'),  // location of your src
            {
                // your Angular Async Route paths relative to this root directory
            }
        ),
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    'angular2-template-loader',
                    'angular-router-loader'
                ]
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            { test: /\.htm(l)*$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
            { test: /\.(eot|svg|cur)$/, loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]" },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
                loader: "url-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]&limit=10000"
            },
        ]
    }

};

var defaultConfig = {
    devtool: 'source-map',

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        ],
    },
};

module.exports = webpackMerge(defaultConfig, webpackConfig);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy, APP_BASE_HREF} from "@angular/common";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {AppRoutesModule} from './app.routes.module';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import HomeModule from "./home/home.module";

@NgModule({

    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule,
        AppRoutesModule,
        HomeModule
    ],

    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],

    providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
    ],

    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {Routes, RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module.js#HomeModule'},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class AppRoutesModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <div>
            App Component
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>`,
})
export class App2Component {}
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {routing} from './home.routes';
import {HomeViewComponent} from "./home-view.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [HomeViewComponent],
    exports: [],
    providers: []
})
export default class HomeModule {}
```

**home.routes.ts**

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from "@angular/core";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {HomeViewComponent} from "./home-view.component";

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
    {path: '', component: HomeViewComponent},
]);
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'home-view',
    template: `<div>Home View</div>`
})
export class HomeViewComponent {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing extension 
`{path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'}`

And also seems there is no `<router-outlet>` to load child routes. Make a component for that.

like

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
{path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
{
  path: '', 
  component: HomeComponent
  children: [
    {path: 'home', component: HomeViewComponent}
 ]
},
```

]);

HomeComponent will have the `router-outlet` for child routes